# What is the convention for packaging JUnit Test classes for both client and server side in GWT?

Tags: gwt

I'm assuming it would go in the same package as the class it is testing. Is that right? I just want to make sure that test classes don't get packaged with the built war file.

Comment: what do you use for packaging? ant or maven?

Comment: Heven't thought of that yet. I don't really know much about building projects. I have maven installed due to some dependencies on github, but I'm curious which one is easier to learn and use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't have a defined idea about what to use, maven or ant, I would recommend that you go with maven.

Using maven, your tests will be in the folder `src/test/java` and your app classes will be in `src/main/java`. You can use the same namespaces so as you can access protected stuff. And maven will not package any test in the final artifact.

To setup a gwt maven project you can do either, create it from scratch which is a hard process, or use a tool for it.

1- In the gwt sdk there is a command to setup a new project with an example test:

```
 webAppCreator -maven -out myproject com.example.myproject
```

2- You can use an archetype to setup a new project, normally I use [gwtquery](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/CreatingNewApplications) one because of its simplicity and it creates an example test.

```
 mvn archetype:generate  -DarchetypeGroupId=com.googlecode.gwtquery \
                         -DarchetypeArtifactId=gquery-archetype  \
                         -DarchetypeVersion=1.3.3 \
                         -DgroupId=com.mycompany \
                         -DartifactId=myproject \
                         -DprojectName=MyProject
```

3- For multimodule projects you have good archetypes by tbroyer [here](https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes), but unfortunately they dont setup any example test.

Comment: Thanks. One more question for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16812283/how-would-you-add-maven-to-an-existing-gwt-project-in-eclipse-with-m2e-installed