# How would you add maven to an existing GWT project in Eclipse with m2e installed?

Tags: eclipse, maven, gwt, gwtquery

The project has GWTQuery included. I'd like to have the pom.xml generated in the existing project so I can configure the build.

Comment: do you mean migrate a non-maven project to maven?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I see is to create a new maven-ready project using gwtquery archetype and setting the same namespaces and module name that you use in your current project.

```
mvn archetype:generate  -DarchetypeGroupId=com.googlecode.gwtquery \
                        -DarchetypeArtifactId=gquery-archetype  \
                        -DarchetypeVersion=1.3.3 \
                        -DgroupId=com.mycompany \
                        -DartifactId=myproject \
                        -DprojectName=MyProject
```

Then import the maven project in eclipse (use m2e plugin) and check if it works (dev mode, tests, etc).

Copy all your source code from your src folder to the new project src/main/java, the same with your public stuff, .gwt.xml file, and tests.

And finally add your dependencies to your pom using the eclipse pom editor.

Note: The m2e feature of converting a normal eclipse project to maven needs a lot of work.

Answer (score 2):

You can start with an empty `pom.xml` by defining your project attributes first and add your dependency to `gwtquery`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.gwtquery</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwtquery</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Another way is to generate a new project using an `archetype`:

Step 1:
`mvn archetype:generate`

Step 2: choose `44`, which at the time of writing means: `44: remote -> com.googlecode.gwtquery:gquery-archetype (This archetype generates a Gwt-2.5.0-rc1 project with all set to use GwtQuery and its plugins.)`

Step 3: enter your project information